# How to force line wrapping in listings package?

Tags: latex

I have a problem concerning the listings package in latex. I need to embed a source code of the following XML document http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/downloads/profiles/EP_Extensions.xml in my master thesis' appendix. The problem is, no matter what options I pass to the package, I don't seem to be able to fit it on the page. The lines in the listing are too long, and the listings package doesn't wrap them, which seems odd... What combination of options will do the trick?

At the moment I use the following lstset instruction:

```
\lstset{
breakindent=0em,
language=XML,
basicstyle=\footnotesize,
numbers=left,
numberstyle=\footnotesize,
stepnumber=2,
numbersep=5pt,
backgroundcolor=\color{white},
showspaces=false,
showstringspaces=false,
showtabs=false,
frame=single,
tabsize=2,
captionpos=b,
breaklines=true,
breakatwhitespace=true,
breakautoindent=true,
escapeinside={\%*}{*)},
linewidth=\textwidth
}
```

Which, with no other options set, and combined with the following command:

```
\lstinputlisting{EP_Extensions.xml}
```

Lists the given file's source to the following output:
[image]

Answer (score 61):

I just had this problem...

`breaklines` worked for me, though you do need to set it to true - the default is false:

```
\lstinputlisting[style=Python,
    caption=My Class,
    label={mine.py},
    breaklines=true,
  ]{../python/mine.py}
```

is pretty much what I used

Comment: A full list of options is available at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Packages/Listings

Answer (score 11):

I had this problem and this page ranks highly on google so here was the solution for me:

I had the following inclusion: `\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}` which causes the issue described above.  I was using it to fix the problem of latex automatically breaking lines in the middle of a word, which looks really stupid in some circumstances.

After much searching for an alternative to this solution I found nothing suitable and settled for properly broken lines but badly placed hyphenation.

Comment: Thank you! I had the exact same problem, and couldn't figure out why listings wouldn't break my lines even with breaklines=true. You just saved me a lot of head scratching.

Comment: Nice find!  I was able to use the `htt` option with monospaced listings - [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50357731/2877364).

Answer (score 2):

Not a great answer, but one idea is to word wrap the source code before including it. If you're on linux, the command **fold** can be used for this. Clearly this works best if the text is in a fixed width font, which i would recommend in any case for code listings.

Answer (score 2):

A followup to [Aaron's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8264050/2877364).  I was using `basicstyle=\ttfamily` for my listings.  I was therefore able to permit line breaking by changing

```
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
```

to

```
\usepackage[htt]{hyphenat}
%           ^^^
```

The [`hyphenat` docs](http://www.ctex.org/documents/packages/special/hyphenat.pdf) describe that the `htt` option "enables hyphenation of ... text typeset via either `\texttt` or `\ttfamily`."  In my use case, I didn't see any hyphenation in my listings, but I did get the breaking.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the packages that you used may be helpful. I had the same problem. Even if I tried, like, everything but I couldn't fix it. Then I delete `\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}` from my document and it worked! This library seems to be causing line break errors because it has disabled automatic hyphenation.